# Is it possible for a material to have a polarization field greater than the applied field?

Tags: electromagnetism, polarization

In the case of a dielectric (LIH at least, since that is all I've studied), the polarization field is always less than the applied field.

In the case of a conductor, the polarization field is equal to the applied field, which is why there is no electric field inside conductors.

Is there any sort of material which has a polarization field greater than the field applied to it? My initial thought is no, since you would be creating a more powerful electric field than you started out with, and that would be a way of creating energy, right?

Comment: What do you mean by the "applied field" and what do you mean by "polarisation field"? In SI units $\vec{P} = \chi_e \epsilon_0 \vec{E}$, so E-field and polarisation field do not have the same units/dimensions and cannot be compared.

Answer (score 1):

Consider parallel plate capacitor with dielectric in between the plates. Let $\mathbf E_0$ be the field in a dielectric due to charge on the parallel capacitor plates, and $\mathbf E_d$ the field due to the dielectric (in fact, due to the polarization charge on its faces). In this case, it can be shown that the depolarization field is given by the formula

$$
\mathbf E_d = - (\epsilon_r - 1) \mathbf E_0.
$$

Water has relative permittivity $\epsilon_r = 80$ at temperature 20 °C, which means that when used as dielectric between the capacitor plates, the depolarization field is 79 times stronger than the external field $\mathbf E_0$. This is not a manifestation of creation of energy. The strong depolarization field is due to high electric moment of water molecules, which due to random orientation cancel each other macroscopically if there is no external electric field, but partially align their orientations if the external field is present. The electrostatic energy of the resulting total electric field comes from the work done to charge the capacitor and some possibly also from the internal energy of the water.